# Parse and watchkit extension

Tags: ios, parse-platform, watchkit, apple-watch

I am building an app using WatchKit and would like to populate a Table with data from PFObjects I have in a class but I got this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'This decoder will
>   only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'PFObject' does
>   not adopt it.'

Having the same problem as [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/QA3H3e_3m5o)

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered adding a Swift extension to PFObject that adopts the NSSecureCoding protocol?

I haven't tried this action but it seems reasonable to expect this to work given the error message.

**Recommended Action**

In order to conform to NSSecureCoding:

An object that does not override initWithCoder: can conform to NSSecureCoding without any changes (assuming that it is a subclass of another class that conforms).

An object that does override initWithCoder: must decode any enclosed objects using the decodeObjectOfClass:forKey: method. For example:

SWIFT

```
let obj = decoder.decodeObjectOfClass(MyClass.self, forKey: "myKey")
```

In addition, the class must override its **supportsSecureCoding** method to return true.

If using Objective-C then a category seems like a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the watch's interface controller simply set call Parse's credentials again:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"APPID" clientKey:@"CLIENTKEY"];
```

and create a new PFQuery just for the watch. It doesn't matter if communication fails or not.